# Why the wrong element is being updated only when uploading files?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have built a component CreatePost which is used for creating or editing posts,
the problem is if I render this component twice even if I upload a file from the second component they are changed in the first one, why? Here is the code:

```
import FileUpload from "@components/form/FileUpload";
import { Attachment, Camera, Video, Writing } from "public/static/icons";
import styles from "@styles/components/Post/CreatePost.module.scss";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useInput, useToggle } from "hooks";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import StyledButton from "@components/buttons/StyledButton";
import Modal from "@components/Modal";
import { post as postType } from "types/Post";
import Removeable from "@components/Removeable";

interface createPostProps {
  submitHandler: (...args) => void;
  post?: postType;
  isEdit?: boolean;
}

const CreatePost: React.FC<createPostProps> = ({ submitHandler, post = null, isEdit = false }) => {
  console.log(post);
  const maxFiles = 10;
  const [showModal, setShowModal, ref] = useToggle();
  const [description, setDescription] = useInput(post?.description || "");
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>(post?.files || []);

  const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    const fileList = Array.from(e.target.files);
    if (fileList.length > maxFiles || files.length + fileList.length > maxFiles) {
      setShowModal(true);
    } else {
      const clonedFiles = [...files, ...fileList];
      setFiles(clonedFiles);
    }
    e.target.value = "";
  };

  const removeHandler = (id) => {
    const filtered = files.filter((file) => file.name !== id);
    setFiles(filtered);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.createPost}>
      <div className={styles.top}>
        <span>
          <img src="/static/images/person1.jpg" />
        </span>

        <textarea
          onChange={setDescription}
          className="primaryScrollbar"
          aria-multiline={true}
          value={description}
          placeholder={`What's on your mind ${user?.name?.split(" ")[0]}`}
        ></textarea>
        {description || files.length ? (
          <StyledButton
            background="bgPrimary"
            size="md"
            className={styles.submitButton}
            onClick={() => {
              if (!isEdit)
                submitHandler({
                  files: files,
                  author: { name: user.name, username: user.username },
                  postedTime: 52345,
                  id: Math.random() * Math.random() * 123456789101112,
                  comments: [],
                  likes: [],
                  description,
                });
              else {
                submitHandler({
                  ...post,
                  description,
                  files,
                });
              }
              setDescription("");
              setFiles([]);
            }}
          >
            {isEdit ? "Edit" : "Post"}
          </StyledButton>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.middle}>
        <div className={styles.row}>
          {files.map((file) => {
            return (
              <Removeable
                key={file.name + Math.random() * 100000}
                removeHandler={() => {
                  removeHandler(file.name);
                }}
              >
                {file.type.includes("image") ? (
                  <img src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} width={150} height={150} />
                ) : (
                  <video>
                    <source src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} type={file.type} />
                  </video>
                )}
              </Removeable>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.bottom}>
        <FileUpload
          id="uploadPhoto"
          label="upload photo"
          icon={
            <span>
              <Camera /> Photo
            </span>
          }
          className={styles.fileUpload}
          multiple
          onChange={handleFileUpload}
          accept="image/*"
        />
        <FileUpload
          id="uploadVideo"
          label="upload video"
          icon={
            <span>
              <Video /> Video
            </span>
          }
          className={styles.fileUpload}
          multiple
          onChange={handleFileUpload}
          accept="video/*"
        />
        <FileUpload
          id="writeArticle"
          label="write article"
          icon={
            <span>
              <Writing /> Article
            </span>
          }
          className={styles.fileUpload}
          multiple
          onChange={handleFileUpload}
        />
      </div>
      {showModal && (
        <Modal size="sm" backdrop="transparent" ref={ref} closeModal={setShowModal.bind(null, false)} yPosition="top">
          <p>Please choose a maximum of {maxFiles} files</p>
          <StyledButton size="md" background="bgPrimary" onClick={setShowModal.bind(null, false)}>
            Ok
          </StyledButton>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreatePost;
```

Now on my main file I have:

```
const Main = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<postType[]>([]);

  const addPost = (post: postType) => {
    setPosts([post, ...posts]);
  };

  const editPost = (post: postType) => {
    const updated = posts.map((p) => {
      if (post.id === post.id) {
        p = post;
      }
      return p;
    });

    setPosts(updated);
  };

  const deletePost = (id) => {
    const filtered = posts.filter((post) => post.id !== id);
    setPosts(filtered);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <CreatePost submitHandler={addPost} key="0" />
      <CreatePost submitHandler={addPost} key="1"/>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        return <PostItem {...post} editHandler={editPost} key={post.id} deleteHandler={deletePost.bind(null, post.id)} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

I tried to add/remove the key but doesn't change anything, also tried to recreate this problem in a simpler way in sandbox but I can't it works fine there. And the problem is only when I upload files not when I write text inside the `<textarea/>`

Note: The second  in reality is shown dynamically inside a modal when clicked edit in a post, but I just showed it here for simplicity because the same problem occurs in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some hours of debugging I finally found the problem.
Because my `<FileUpload/>` uses id to target the input inside the `<CreatePost/>` the `<FileUpload/>` always had same it, so when I used `<CreatePost/>` more than 1 time it would target the first element that found with that id that's why the first component was being updated